# How can I check if string value in two columns also exists in another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So there are 3 columns, first name, last name, and description.
What I want to do is to check if first name or last name, or both, exist in description.
I believe using Like operator might help, but not sure how to write it.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here, [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysqli]]. Retag the related technologies you are using. `mysqli` is a PHP extension for *MySQL* so tagging it along side SQL Server makes little sense.

Comment: What about upper/lower case? Do you want to find Tim in 'TIM IS A GREAT GUY'? What about concatenations? Do you want to find Tim in 'Tom is a great guy. Timid, but great.'?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for all the very helpful comments. I am indeed new here so thanks for being patient with me. It would be great if case sensitivity is considered as well. (Btw I am using Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: You can always edit your request (by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68623993/edit) link under it). I have added the `sql-server` tag now. And I understand your comment such that you want this to be case sensitive ('Tim' does not equal 'TIM') and you don't care if you get false positives ('Timid' when looking for 'Tim'). This makes the task much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression and `like`.  In Standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select t.*,
       (case when description like '%' || firstname || '%' or
                  description like '%' || lastname || '%'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as in_description_flag
from t;
```

This uses the SQL standard operator for string concatenation.  Some databases have bespoke operators (such as `+`) or bespoke functions (such as `concat()`).

EDIT:

In SQL Server:

```
select t.*,
       (case when description like '%' + firstname + '%' or
                  description like '%' + lastname + '%'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as in_description_flag
from t;
```

Comment: Standard SQL! Is that what's it called? I figured ANSI SQL might be more fitting. I think the is no official name otherwise

Comment: @TheDudeWithHat . . . Some non-American was once offended that I used the term ANSI.  So now I just go with Standard SQL.

Comment: @TheDudeWithHat: "ISO/IEC 9075" is the official name, but we use "Standard SQL" for convenience. It is developed ISO/IEC. If I am not mistaken, this standard is adopted by ANSI and labeled "ANSI X3.135". (The first standard on the other hand was developed by ANSI in 1989 and adopted by ISO in 1987 :-) Anyway, have you been able to adapt Gordon's query to SQL Server? Then please accept his answer with the tick next to it.